# Ping sending/delivery to remote server is slow

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ubuntu-12.04, ping

I am facing some weird issue. I am trying to ping one remote server with 1 second interval. ping packet sending/delivery is too slow ( not response time). See below output. I am facing this issue with particular domain only and from this server only. If I ping from other machine it is fine. I am clueless. Please help.

```
root@beta:/usr/local/src$ date ; ping -i 1 -c 10 domain.com | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: {}' ; date 
Tue Apr 10 15:15:00 IST 2018
2018-04-10 15:15:24: PING catchall.domain.com.cdn.cloudflare.net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
2018-04-10 15:15:24: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=1 ttl=59 time=15.6 ms
2018-04-10 15:15:49: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=2 ttl=59 time=15.3 ms
2018-04-10 15:16:14: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=3 ttl=59 time=16.0 ms
2018-04-10 15:16:39: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=4 ttl=59 time=20.5 ms
2018-04-10 15:16:54: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=6 ttl=59 time=19.0 ms
2018-04-10 15:17:10: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=7 ttl=54 time=30.4 ms
2018-04-10 15:17:35: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=8 ttl=59 time=32.0 ms
2018-04-10 15:18:00: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=9 ttl=59 time=15.4 ms
2018-04-10 15:18:25: 64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=10 ttl=59 time=15.7 ms
2018-04-10 15:18:25: --- catchall.domain.com.cdn.cloudflare.net ping statistics ---
2018-04-10 15:18:25: 10 packets transmitted, 9 received, 10% packet loss, time 179731ms
2018-04-10 15:18:25: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.324/20.022/32.001/6.227 ms
Tue Apr 10 15:18:25 IST 2018
root@beta:/usr/local/src$
```

Please help me to figure out from where this delay is coming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try to ping the IP instead? Also, please show us the output of `dig domain.com`.

Comment: Thanks sven.  This domain is having cloudflare (DDOS protection DNS). So IP is hidden by this service. But if I ping some other domain say google.com , it is working properly. Do you think it is server issue or this cloudflare is cause issue

Comment: But you edited out the IP (`64 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`). Again, try to ping that `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` IP in order to determine if there are some issues with DNS resolution.

Comment: "_rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.324/20.022/32.001/6.227 ms_" That doesn't actually look too bad for a ping of five hops across the public Internet.